# n-dataframes inner joined to final dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to figure out how to inner merge n-dataframes to a single final dataframe.

I need to be able to specify a list of dataframes in which the inner join of **all** is output as another dataframe. Again, the exact number will not be known in advance, but the integer count can be.

See the below code:

```
import pandas as pd


result = pd.merge(df_1, df_2, on=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4'], how='inner')
result_2 = pd.merge(df_3, df_4, on=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4'], how='inner')
result_final = pd.merge(result, result_2, on=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4'], how='inner')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
dflist = [df1, df2, df3, df4]
result_final = reduce(lambda x,y: x.merge(y, 
                         on=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4'], 
                         how='inner'), 
                     dflist)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cols = ['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4']

pd.concat([d.set_index(cols) for d in [df_1, df_2, df_3, df_4]], axis=1)
```